# избавиться от явного указания типа шаблонной функции

Tags: c++

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
bool read_node_att(const std::string& root, const std::string& att_name, T& param, std::string& error, std::function<T(const std::string&)> conv)
{
    param = conv(att_name);
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    std::string error;
    int i = 5;

    read_node_att<int>("5", "", i, error, [](const std::string& value) -> int { return 42; });

    read_node_att("5", "", i, error, [](const std::string& value) -> int { return 42; }); // error

    return 0;
}
```

Есть шаблон функции, которая принимает аргументом функцию преобразования из строки к типу переменной, можно ли избавиться от явного указания типа шаблона?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - сделать функтор шаблонным параметром. В этом случае также можно избавиться от оверхеда на создание объекта `std::function`:

```
template <typename T, typename Convert>
bool read_node_att(const std::string& root, const std::string& att_name, T& param, std::string& error, Convert const & conv)
```

В качестве альтернативы можно поместить `T` в сигнатуре функтора в невыводимый контекст посредством `::std::type_identity` (доступного с C++20):

```
template<typename T> struct
type_identity
{
    using type = T;
};
template<typename T> using
type_identity_t = typename type_identity<T>::type;

template <typename T> bool
read_node_att
(
    const std::string& root
,   const std::string& att_name
,   T& param
,   std::string& error
,   std::function<type_identity_t<T> (const std::string&)> conv)
)
```

Comment: спасибо, вариант с с++20 интересный.  в чем смысл такой записи `Convert const & conv` ? ссылки же константные по умолчанию

Comment: @goldstar_labs В С++ объявления типов читаются по спиральному правилу. `const` квалификатор применяется к тому, что стоит слева от него, а не справа, за исключением ситуации, когда слева от него ничего нет.